# Getting selected index of ComboBox in Devexpress Ribbon

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, devexpress

I have searched a lot about this problem and I found this way:

```
cmbUnits.Items.IndexOf(cmbunit.EditValue)
```

Which in this code `cmbUnits` is a `repositoryItem` that is assigned to main control which is named `cmbunit`. This works but the only problem is that `cmbunit.EditValue` represents previous selected item. But I just want to get current selected index of combo box.

Is there any way to fix this problem? (I am in winforms version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Source:** [RepositoryItemComboBox: how to obtain a selected index when an edit value is changed](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q294689)

> When you change an edit value of an in-place ComboBoxEdit and then you
>   can obtain its SelectedIndex property's value.
>
> To achieve the required result, handle the
>   [RepositoryItemComboBox.EditValueChanged event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItem_EditValueChangedtopic) , cast the sender
>   to ComboBoxEdit and access its [ComboBoxEdit.SelectedIndex
>   property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsComboBoxEdit_SelectedIndextopic) .

In case, if you want to get selected index from combox inside grid then follow the below devexpress thread:
[Get selectedindex of repositoryitemcombobox](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q107903)